# codeigniter populate form from database

Tags: forms, codeigniter

In the controller, I have...

```
function update($id = null)
{
    $this->load->database();

    // more code

    $data = array();
    $data = $this->db->get_where(
            'users',
            array(
            'id' => $id
            )
        );
    $data = $data->result_array();
    $data = $data[0];

    // more code

    $this->load->view('update', $data);
}
```

In the view, I have...

```
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Email</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Email Confirmation</h5>
<input type="text" name="emailconf" value="<?php echo set_value('emailconf'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirmation</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>" size="50" />
```

set_value() isn't reading $data

search for value=""

at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103837/

The poster uses only the set_value() function between "" in value="".

I'm wondering how to do the same, but I can't get it to work. Help?

Comment: Why are you pulling data in the controller instead of the model?

Comment: because he (we) can... and want to. ;)

Answer (score 21):

set_value requires 2 parameters. field name AND value.

You need:

```
value="<?php echo set_value('username', $username); ?>"
```

assuming that you are passing $data['username'] etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It takes care of the case of prepopulating the form from the database + populating form validation user input

Comment: Its correct, but one more thing will save you tons of time if you replace your System/helpers/set_value code like suggested here http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159535/#775628 to avoid problems when repopulating form again when rule doesnt exist.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are not passing the value correctly to the view.

In the Controller put:

```
$data = $this->db->get_where(
        'users',
        array(
        'id' => $id
        )
    );
$data = $data->result_array();

$data['result'] = $data[0];
```

then inside the view:

```
<h5>Password Confirmation</h5> <input type="text" name="passconf" value="<?php echo $result['passconf']; ?>" size="50" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Controller:

```
$data = array();
$data = $this->db->get_where(
        'users',
        array(
        'id' => $id
        )
    );
$data = $data->result_array();
$data['view_username'] = $data['username'];
```

Instead of using $date[0], I use the column name, but that's your decision

View:

```
<h5>Username</h5> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$view_username?>" size="50"/>
```

`<?= =>` is PHP short tag, read about it in the codeigniter user guide

Regards,

Sylvio

Answer (score 1):

set_value() is designed to work with CI form validation.

When the form is first loaded, set_value() can fill the field with a default value using its second parameter. After the form is submitted, you can display the form again and the field will be filled with the value that was submitted providing it was checked for validation.

See also http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/96617/ - there are a few gotchas with set_value() that the docs don't clarify.

Applicable up to CI 1.7.3 so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try to assign default values to `$_POST` variable in your controller, e.g. `$_POST['email'] = 'email';`

Comment: You can't set any $_POST values.